# Silverstripe - google connect

Tags: php, content-management-system, openid, silverstripe

I am trying to make google connect/openid work in silverstripe but I am getting this error and I don't understand its error at all.

```
[Notice] Trying to get property of non-object
GET /GoogleCallback/GoogleConnect

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 'Accept: application/xrds+xml')
        ));

    $xml = curl_exec($ch);      
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $discovery = $xml->XRD->Service->URI->__toString();

    curl_close($ch);

    $params = array(
        'openid.mode' => 'checkid_setup',
        'openid.ns' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0',
```

PS: I am using this module https://github.com/MediaDevils/silverstripe-google-authentication

Answer (score 1):

It would help to tell us which line exactly triggered that error but I guess it would be in

```
$discovery = $xml->XRD->Service->URI->__toString();
```

It is quite likely that you are not getting the expected XML response (it can be for many reasons, so the module itself might not be the root cause of your issue). You could for example dump the content of the $xml variable in order to know more about what you get back. Something like

```
Debug::Dump($xml);
Debug::Dump(curl_error($ch));
```

after the curl_exec($ch);

Hope this helps

Comment: hi jfbarrois. Thanks for the suggestion but I have no idea how to deal with this. Here is the output, hope you could help

_SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed_

Comment: We're getting closer. Are you on windows? If so your error might likely be related to what's described on that page : http://richardwarrender.com/2007/05/the-secret-to-curl-in-php-on-windows/